# How to make Windows remember the "Show this window on all Desktops" option even after closing the window?

Tags: windows-10, window, virtual-desktop, multitasking

I am able to make a window appear on all of my Virtual Desktops by launching the Task View and Right-Click on the Window and select Show this window on all Desktops.

But when I close that window and re-open it again, that option is not enabled anymore. Is there a way to tweak around this?

Comment: Anyone got an answer? :)

Comment: @Denny : I do .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if you want this to apply to *all* windows of that app.

1. Have more than one virtual desktops and the [app you want to show on all desktops] displayed on the current one [(Source)](https://superuser.com/a/1674974/89165)
2. Enter Task View either by the taskbar icon
   [image]
   or the shortcut
   <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [(Source)](https://superuser.com/a/1674974/89165)
3. Right click on a window associated with the application you want to open on all desktops
4. Select "Show windows from this app on all desktops":
   [image]

Now, when you **restart the app, it'll automatically show on all virtual desktops.** (I'm not sure why, but the option above it does not persist.)

Comment: OMG this seems to work!! I've been looking for this forever… Will update my comment here if I find cases this DOESN'T work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will detect one window whose
title contains the string "Untitled - Notepad" and will set it to
show on all desktops. Modify the title as required.

```
#Persistent
DetectHiddenText, On
SetTitleMatchMode 2

SetTimer, ShowAllDesktops, 500 
Return 

ShowAllDesktops:
if WinExist("Untitled - Notepad") {
    WinGet, exstyle, ExStyle
    If  !(exstyle & 0x00000080)        ; visible on all desktops
        WinSet, exstyle, 0x00000080
}
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [WinExist()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinExist.htm)

Comment: I just want to confirm that this is AHK v1, not v2, correct? I'm really sorry but I forgot to check-in over Christmas break and my bounty expired. I would've given it to you if I logged in sooner.

Comment: Yes, this is AHK v1.

Answer (score -3):

You have to check as in the picture and it works! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsmiI.jpg

And after there it is necessary to look in the chrome options so that at its next opening it launches all the tabs of the previous session
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu3mC.jpg

Comment: This is good for a non-tabbed window. But what about a window with multiple tabs (say Chrome)?

Comment: Can you please explain the steps in English? Or at least attach an English Screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/7zA6e7g

Comment: this is still not english

Comment: I haven't been helping for long and I haven't yet understood all the subtleties of the forum and the answers I hope it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @lejurassien, the only issue is that your screenshots are not in English. I believe all questions and answers on StackOverflow need to be in English.